# Como usar o Firebase com Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Queria pegar os campos de texto, e salvar no banco, só que não sei como salvar no firebase.

```
TelaOpcoes : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_opcoes)
        setListeners()
    }
    private fun setListeners() {
        nPla?.doAfterTextChanged { text ->
        }
        item?.doAfterTextChanged { text ->
        }
        locaL?.doAfterTextChanged { text ->
        }
        btNCa.setOnClickListener {
            btNCaL(nPla.text.toString())
        }
    }
    private fun btNCaL(item: Any) {
    }Texto pré-formatado
}
```

Comment: Duplicada da [519052](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/519052/como-usar-o-firebase-com-kotlin), e como comentado na outra pergunta, ela está muito vaga.

Answer (score 0):

Cara tenta dar uma olhada nessa documentação do FireBase:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#kotlin+ktx

Eu usei ela para conseguir implementar o FireBase no meu projeto e justamente para salvar campos de texto digitados no app.

Dica: Tive que criar uma classe de "Dados" para conseguir salvar os dados escritos pelo usuário e depois dar um getInstace pro FireBase usando o Cloud Firestore.